# I am trying to access config.properties file but unable to access. Can anyone help me?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
  package pageObjects;

  import java.io.FileInputStream;

  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.Properties;


 public class ReadProperty {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String fileName = "config.properties";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    prop.load(input);


    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("UserName"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Password"));

}
```

}

Getting error as Below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   pageObjects.ReadProperty.main(ReadProperty.java:16)

Comment: Where you have put your config.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

The program can't open a connection with the *config.properties* file, and it might be for two reasons:

1. The file doesn't exist.
2. Its name or path is not correct.

I guess it's not the first option, so you can try changing `String fileName = "config.properties";` with the complete path of the file.

If the file isn't in the same folder where you're executing your program and you don't specify the complete path, it won't find it. So this way you will be always sure the program is able to find it regardless of your working directory.

Comment: Your welcome @PardeepKochhar, if it fits you please click on the green check to choose it as right answer.